# What was the floppy disk in this scene from The Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

I remember in movie The-Matrix when Neo's computer is hacked by Trinity in the beginning of the movie then when Neo tries to delete the message "follow the white rabbit" then all of a sudden there is this banging on the door, and Neo said "Who is this" and the other guy on the door replied "Its troy", then what happened that Neo gave the guy some sort of floppy and told him "If you got caught using that". I am wondering what was on that floppy or whatever it was that made Neo say that?

Comment: I believe it was a program made by Neo to clear the guys parking tickets but that may not be canon I think I read it in another question answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo's a computer hacker, as explained in the scene where Agent Smith is interrogating him. I imagine the disc has an illegal program on it that Neo created. Perhaps the customer (I think he name is actually Choi) wants to use it as a weapon or for some kind of corporate espionage. Neo knows full well how illegal it is and wants to make sure Choi won't drop Neo's name if he's caught.